# Не понимаю как создать endpoint для бота Dialog

Tags: python, сервер, бот, dialog

Я хочу создать бота для мессенджера [Dialog](https://dlg.im) используя офф.библиотеку [python-bot-sdk](https://github.com/dialogs/python-bot-sdk).

Я работаю в корпоративной сети из под прокси.

Я пытаюсь создать стандартного эхо бота из [документации](https://dialogs.github.io/bots-docs/#/usage)

```
from dialog_bot_sdk.bot import DialogBot
import grpc

def on_msg(*params):
    print('on msg', params)
    bot.messaging.send_message(
        params[0].peer, 'Reply to : ' + str(params[0].message.textMessage.text))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = DialogBot.get_secure_bot(
        'hackathon-mob.transmit.im', #endpoint
        grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(),
        'PUT YOUR BOT TOKEN HERE',
        verbose=False
    
    bot.messaging.on_message(on_msg)
```

В документации используется `hackathon-mob.transmit.im` как endpoint, но я не могу его использовать из под прокси (он заблокирован).

My error:

```
ERROR:root:Failed request to server, with error: UNAVAILABLE
details: DNS resolution failed for service: hackathon-mob.transmit.im
debug string: {"created":"@1631196496.373000000","description":"Resolver transient failure","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":1361,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1631196496.373000000","description":"DNS resolution failed for service: hackathon-mob.transmit.im","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/native/dns_resolver.cc","file_line":201,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1631196496.373000000","description":"OS Error","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":95,"os_error":"No such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}]}
retry: 1 / 10
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать в данной ситуации.

Comment: А Вы в другой сети проверяли адрес? Мне возвращается `DNS Error`

Comment: Нет, в другой сети не проверял, на днях постараюсь на домашнем компьютере проверить.